# testing ember.js apps with jasmine

Tags: integration-testing, ember.js, jasmine

Does anyone know of any resources, examples or tutorials about testing ember.js apps ?

How do you test views ?

There does not seem to be any extensive examples / information on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can't propose an example how you can achieve that, but I have found a project which extensively uses Jasmine for their test: you should take a look at the [ember-resource](https://github.com/zendesk/ember-resource) project on GitHub. It uses Jasmine for their tests, which are located in [spec/javascripts](https://github.com/zendesk/ember-resource/tree/master/spec/javascripts).

The project also has a `Rakefile` and corresponding tasks which let you execute the specs in a convenient way.

---

There is a blog post about testing Ember.js with Jasmine: http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/04/03/testing-ember-and-the-runloop/

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the testing functionality of Ember itself, as described in [this post](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/19/testing-ember-dot-js-part-1/)

What is basically does is disabling the Ember runloop by setting: `Ember.testing = true`
This way you don't have to check if your asynchronous code is finished. You simple could wrap it in its own runloop:

```js
// Creating an application normally happens async,
// which is why we have to wrap it in Ember.run
Ember.run(function() {
  App = Ember.Application.create();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on using Jasmine to test Ember.js http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2014-1-ember-js-testing-with-jasmine