# How do you structure your Ember app with unit tests in mind?

Tags: ember.js

I haven't written unit testing with JS before and I'm still learning ember and javascript in general, so forgive the question for its simplicity.

Ember apps are structured by first creating a namespace for the app like so:

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create({...})
```

Then you'd define a model like so:

```
MyApp.SomeModel = DS.Model.extend({...})
```

But when I'm writing a unit test for `SomeModel`, it doesn't seem right to instantiate an `Ember.Application` instance when you're just unit testing a model, especially with all the `Router` injections and such going on behind the scenes.

However, to define the model you need the app namespace, `MyApp.SomeModel` ..  and that app name space is created when the `Application` is instantiated (if you follow the Ember namespace convention).

So how do you unit test a model without instantiating the app? Do you create a mock for the app namespace?

I'm using jasmine btw.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253339/testing-ember-js-apps-with-jasmine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create a dummy instance of Ember.Application. It's not particularly costly to do.

Comment: thanks luke, i've wound up doing the same thing, but i wasn't sure of the cost.

Comment: do you create a dummy instance with each unit test?  or one dummy instance for a collection of unit tests?